# CryptImportKey DSA key

Tags: c++, winapi, ssl, cryptography

I have DSA private/public key pair in two PEM files. I want to import them and then use them with SChannel.

For the public key I use `CryptStringToBinary` and `CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore` to add the public key to the store.

For the private key, seems that a "[DSS Version 3 Private Key BLOBs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381988(v=vs.85).aspx)" must be used with [CryptImportKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380207(v=vs.85).aspx), but I'm not sure how to create this BLOB from the PEM file.

How do I import a DSS key for use in SChannel?